# How to conditionally select a column, and subtract values in those rows from rows in another conditionally selected column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble, mutate

*I understand that my question title is quite wordy and may be difficult to understand so I'll try my best to explain it here.*

Here is some example  data:

```r
transactions <- tibble(id = seq(1:7),
                       day = paste(rep("day", each = 7), seq(1:7), sep = ""),
                       sent_to = c(NA, "Garden Cinema", "Pasta House", NA, "Blue Superstore", "Jane", "Joe"),
                       received_from = c("ATM", NA, NA, "Sarah", NA, NA, NA),
                       reference = c("add_cash", "cinema_tickets", "meal", "gift", "shopping", "reimbursed", "reimbursed"),
                       decrease = c(NA, 10.8, 12.5, NA, 15.25, NA, NA),
                       increase = c(50, NA, NA, 30, NA, 5.40, 7.25),
                       reimbursed_id = c(NA, "R", "R", NA, NA, 2, 3))
# # A tibble: 7 × 7
#      id   day   sent_to         received_from reference      decrease  increase reimbursed_id
#    <int>  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <chr>
# 1     1   day1  NA              ATM           add_cash       NA        50       NA
# 2     2   day2  Garden Cinema   NA            cinema_tickets 10.8      NA       R
# 3     3   day3  Pasta House     NA            meal           12.5      NA       R
# 4     4   day4  NA              Sarah         gift           NA        30       NA
# 5     5   day5  Blue Superstore NA            shopping       15.2      NA       NA
# 6     6   day6  Jane            NA            reimbursed     NA        5.4      2
# 7     7   day7  Joe             NA            reimbursed     NA        7.25     3
```

*Explanation for `reimbursed_id` column:*

- `R` indicates the value in the decrease column is not representative of the user's actual spending because it includes the amount paid on someone's behalf
- `2` (or any number) represents the `id` for which the user was reimbursed (returned the borrowed amount)

*Desired outcome:*

I would like to add an "actual_decrease" column to this dataset which essentially looks through the `reimbursed_id` column for numerical values, collects the reimbursed amount in the `increase` column and subtracts it from the values in the `decrease` for the respective `id`'s.

I'm not sure how to better explain this, so here is what the desired result looks like:

```r
# # A tibble: 7 × 9
#      id   day   sent_to         received_from reference      decrease  increase reimbursed_id  actual_decrease
#    <int>  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <chr>          <dbl>
# 1     1   day1  NA              ATM           add_cash       NA        50       NA             NA
# 2     2   day2  Garden Cinema   NA            cinema_tickets 10.8      NA       R              5.4
# 3     3   day3  Pasta House     NA            meal           12.5      NA       R              5.25
# 4     4   day4  NA              Sarah         gift           NA        30       NA             NA
# 5     5   day5  Blue Superstore NA            shopping       15.2      NA       NA             15.2
# 6     6   day6  Jane            NA            reimbursed     NA        5.4      2              NA
# 7     7   day7  Joe             NA            reimbursed     NA        7.25     3              NA
```

I can't think of any functions that could help solve this besides a really complicated `ifelse()` statement, and maybe a for loop (but I'd prefer to avoid loops).

Note that it is also preferred that your answer doesn't involve the row numbers, instead the `id` column, because for my actual dataset these values do not correspond.

Any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to approach this issue would be via a join. Basically I first create a helper df by filtering for the "reimbursed" transactions which could then be joined to the original df to finally compute the `actual_decrease`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

transactions_help <- transactions |> 
  filter(reference == "reimbursed") |> 
  select(reimbursed_decrease = increase, reimbursed_id) |> 
  mutate(reimbursed_id = as.numeric(reimbursed_id))

transactions <- transactions |> 
  left_join(transactions_help, by = c("id" = "reimbursed_id")) |> 
  replace_na(list(reimbursed_decrease = 0)) |> 
  mutate(actual_decrease = decrease - reimbursed_decrease)

transactions
#> # A tibble: 7 × 10
#>      id day   sent_to    recei…¹ refer…² decre…³ incre…⁴ reimb…⁵ reimb…⁶ actua…⁷
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 day1  <NA>       ATM     add_ca…    NA     50    <NA>       0      NA   
#> 2     2 day2  Garden Ci… <NA>    cinema…    10.8   NA    R          5.4     5.4 
#> 3     3 day3  Pasta Hou… <NA>    meal       12.5   NA    R          7.25    5.25
#> 4     4 day4  <NA>       Sarah   gift       NA     30    <NA>       0      NA   
#> 5     5 day5  Blue Supe… <NA>    shoppi…    15.2   NA    <NA>       0      15.2 
#> 6     6 day6  Jane       <NA>    reimbu…    NA      5.4  2          0      NA   
#> 7     7 day7  Joe        <NA>    reimbu…    NA      7.25 3          0      NA   
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​received_from, ²​reference, ³​decrease,
#> #   ⁴​increase, ⁵​reimbursed_id, ⁶​reimbursed_decrease, ⁷​actual_decrease
```

Comment: would appreciate it if you could have a look at this one too pls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563048/how-to-conditionally-subtract-values-in-one-column-from-another-conditionally-se