# How to conditionally subtract values in one column from another conditionally selected column with duplicates, in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble, mutate

Here is some example data:

```r
transactions <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), day = c("day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day6", "day7", "day8"), sent_to = c(NA, 
"Garden Cinema", "Pasta House", NA, "Blue Superstore", NA, NA, 
NA), received_from = c("ATM", NA, NA, "Sarah", NA, "Jane", "Joe", 
"Emily"), reference = c("add_cash", "cinema_tickets", "meal", 
"gift", "shopping", "reimbursed", "reimbursed", "reimbursed"), 
    decrease = c(NA, 10.8, 12.5, NA, 15.25, NA, NA, NA), increase = c(50, 
    NA, NA, 30, NA, 5.4, 7.25, 2), reimbursed_id = c(NA, "R", 
    "R", NA, NA, "2", "3", "3")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#      id    day sent_to         received_from reference      decrease increase reimbursed_id
#   <dbl>  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>        
# 1     1   day1  NA              ATM           add_cash           NA      50    NA           
# 2     2   day2  Garden Cinema   NA            cinema_tickets     10.8    NA    R            
# 3     3   day3  Pasta House     NA            meal               12.5    NA    R            
# 4     4   day4  NA              Sarah         gift               NA      30    NA           
# 5     5   day5  Blue Superstore NA            shopping           15.2    NA    NA           
# 6     6   day6  NA              Jane          reimbursed         NA       5.4  2            
# 7     7   day7  NA              Joe           reimbursed         NA       7.25 3            
# 8     8   day8  NA              Emily         reimbursed         NA       2    3
```

Note that this is linked to a question I have previously asked here:
[How to conditionally select a column, and subtract values in those rows from rows in another conditionally selected column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550067/how-to-conditionally-select-a-column-and-subtract-values-in-those-rows-from-row)

I would like a similar solution to the above question but this time accounting for the fact that there are multiple people who are reimbursing the user for the same day.

This is the desired outcome:

```r
#      id   day   sent_to         received_from reference      decrease  increase reimbursed_id  actual_decrease
#    <int>  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <chr>          <dbl>
# 1     1   day1  NA              ATM           add_cash       NA        50       NA             NA
# 2     2   day2  Garden Cinema   NA            cinema_tickets 10.8      NA       R              5.4
# 3     3   day3  Pasta House     NA            meal           12.5      NA       R              3.25
# 4     4   day4  NA              Sarah         gift           NA        30       NA             NA
# 5     5   day5  Blue Superstore NA            shopping       15.2      NA       NA             15.2
# 6     6   day6  NA              Jane          reimbursed     NA        5.4      2              NA
# 7     7   day7  NA              Joe           reimbursed     NA        7.25     3              NA
# 8     8   day8  NA              Emily         reimbursed     NA        2        3              NA
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should first summarise the increase per id:

```
increase_df <- transactions %>% 
  filter(!is.na(as.numeric(reimbursed_id))) %>%
  group_by(id = as.numeric(reimbursed_id)) %>%
  summarise(increase_sum = sum(increase))

     id increase_sum
  <dbl>        <dbl>
1     2         5.4 
2     3         9.25
```

To then merge it and make the subtraction:

```
left_join(transactions,increase_df,by = "id") %>%
  mutate(decrease = ifelse(!is.na(increase_sum),decrease - increase_sum,decrease))
```

```
     id day   sent_to         received_from reference      decrease increase reimbursed_id increase_sum
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
1     1 day1  NA              ATM           add_cash          NA       50    NA                   NA   
2     2 day2  Garden Cinema   NA            cinema_tickets     5.4     NA    R                     5.4 
3     3 day3  Pasta House     NA            meal               3.25    NA    R                     9.25
4     4 day4  NA              Sarah         gift              NA       30    NA                   NA   
5     5 day5  Blue Superstore NA            shopping          15.2     NA    NA                   NA   
6     6 day6  NA              Jane          reimbursed        NA        5.4  2                    NA   
7     7 day7  NA              Joe           reimbursed        NA        7.25 3                    NA   
8     8 day8  NA              Emily         reimbursed        NA        2    3                    NA
```